# Covering by generators

Tags: ct.category-theory, abelian-categories

Let $\mathcal A$ be an abelian category which contains all colimits. Let $\mathcal P$ be a full subcategory of generating objects. You may assume them to be projective. Is it true that for any $X\in \mathcal A$ there is an epimorphism $\bigoplus_{i\in I}P_i\twoheadrightarrow X$ with all $P_i$ in $\mathcal P$?

The definition of ''generating'' that I use here is that for any two morphisms $f,g:X\to Y$ such that $f\circ p=g\circ p$ for any morphism $p:P\to X$ with $P\in\mathcal P$, we have $f=g$.
If for a given $X$, you could take a small subcategory of $\mathcal P$, the problem is solved, but in general, for fixed $X$, the object $Y$ may vary over a true class of objects and therefore, one cannot assume to restrict to a small category.

Comment: Since the issues here are of a set-theoretic nature, could you spell out a bit more what framework you're using? For instance, are you assuming $\mathcal A$ is locally small? What does 'class' mean for you (my understanding is that it not a formal notion in ZFC, but there are other systems where you can formally talk about these)? I think if you assume universes and take small to mean $\mathscr U$-small, there should be easy counterexamples if you allow categories that are not $\mathscr U$-locally small.

Comment: @R. van Dobben de Bruyn: I take locally smallness to be part of the definition of a category. Otherwise, yes I think one gets easy counterexamples.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, you do not need the assumption about the class of subobjects being a set. The statement is true in any cocomplete abelian category, i.e., one with colimits, as you wrote (in fact, arbitrary coproducts is enough). A proof is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3023649/definition-of-generator-in-an-abelian-category) by Eric Wofsey.

That link is also useful because it spells out what is meant by "generator" namely that $Hom(G,-)$ is faithful where $G = \bigoplus P_i$ for you. Wofsey proves that the natural projection from $\bigoplus_{f:G\to X} \limits G$ to $X$ is en epimorphism.

Comment: I don't see how that answers the question. If you want to take $G$ as the sum you gave, what is this sum indexed by? In my question the subcategory $\mathcal P$ is not small, so the notation doesn't even make sense.